# PLS-00103 when trying to call a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, pls-00103

When attempting to compile I am getting the following errors

> Error(16,8): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SPROLLUPEXPENSEITEM"
>   when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; The symbol ":="
>   was substituted for "SPROLLUPEXPENSEITEM" to continue.

and

> Error(17,15): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one
>   of the following:     . ( * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder
>   not rem then     <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like
>   like2    like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset

```
create or replace
TRIGGER tr_ExpenseItem_Rollup
AFTER DELETE OR UPDATE of ExpApprAmt
ON ExpenseItem
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    RollupAmt   Number;
    BlnResult   Boolean;
BEGIN
    IF DELETING THEN
        RollupAmt := -1 * :Old.ExpApprAmt;
    End If;
    IF UPDATING Then
        RollupAmt := :New.ExpApprAmt - :Old.ExpApprAmt;
    End IF;
  Call spRollUpExpenseItem(:New.ERNo,:New.ECNo,RollupAmt,BlnResult);
    If BlnResult := TRUE
        --Additional Logic Here 
    End IF;
END;
```

I'm a student and *very* new at this, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`call` isn't a keyword in PL/SQL and to run a stored procedure you just use its name. Remove `call` from before `spRollUpExpenseItem`:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER tr_ExpenseItem_Rollup
AFTER DELETE OR UPDATE of ExpApprAmt
ON ExpenseItem
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    RollupAmt   Number;
    BlnResult   Boolean;
BEGIN
    IF DELETING THEN
        RollupAmt := -1 * :Old.ExpApprAmt;
    End If;
    IF UPDATING Then
        RollupAmt := :New.ExpApprAmt - :Old.ExpApprAmt;
    End IF;
    spRollUpExpenseItem(:New.ERNo,:New.ECNo,RollupAmt,BlnResult);
    If BlnResult = TRUE Then
        --Additional Logic Here 
    End IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe your problem is in the last if statement. You're missing `Then` and you're using `:=` which is the assignment operator, you should use `=` instead.

```
If BlnResult = TRUE Then
```

or just

```
If BlnResult Then
```

Comment: Thanks Simon.  That eliminates one error, however the error at 16,8 still remains.

Comment: Ah yeah, missed that part, sorry. Doyle has given you the answer - remove `call`